# how to write a relational algebriac expression for the following query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, relational-algebra

how to write a relational algebriac expression for the following query?

```
select Customer_ID
from tbl_Reservation
where Customer_ID not in (select Customer_ID from tbl_Bill)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
excludedCustomers = π(Customer_ID)(tbl_Bill)
customerReservations= π(Customer_ID)(tbl_Reservation)
result = customerReservations- excludedCustomers
```

You just need to get the projection of the customers you want to exclude (all from the tbl_Bill), do the same for tbl_Reservation and the subtraction from both projections is your answer.